# What are the names (/terms) for an anticipated-but-missing rhyme?

Tags: single-word-requests, rhymes

Sometimes in songs or poetry we are set-up to expect a rhyming word but instead another word is supplied. An example is the Killers song *Mr Brightside*:

> *Now they're going to bed.
>
>   And my stomach is sick.
>
>   And it's all in my head.
>
>   But she's touching his chest*

To my recollection I've heard these called several different things in the distant past.

So what are these anticipated but missing rhymes (or the works that contain them) called?

Answer (score 4):

It's a *[mind rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_rhyme)*. From Wikipedia:

> the suggestion of a rhyme which is left unsaid and must be inferred by the listener.

Wikipedia gives this example:

> There was a young farmer who took a young miss
>   to the back of the barn where he gave her a lecture

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm pretty sure that's one of the terms I had heard.

Comment: I'll leave a little time before trying to award the tick in case further answers show up

Answer (score 2):

With the help of Laurel's answer I managed to find a couple of alternate names via Google:

It's sometimes called a [*subverted rhyme*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SubvertedRhymeEveryOccasion) or a *teasing rhyme*.

*Subverted rhyme* was the one on the tip of my tongue.