# Phrase Request: Lyric Subversion

Tags: phrase-requests, lyrics, rhymes, music

I've noticed this quite often from Disney sound tracks.

Lyrics are in a certain rhyming scheme - one line happens and the next line approaches the end of the line, but the last word subverts the rhyme.

I have looked at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168461/is-there-a-term-for-this-word-play-where-a-song-intentionally-avoids-completing) and feel it's related, but not the same effect.

Example:
"In Summer" from Olaf in Frozen

> Da da, da doo, a bubba bubba boo
> The hot and the cold are both so intense
> Put them together ? it just makes sense!

> Rata ta ta dada dada da doo
> Winter's a good time to stay in and cuddle
> But put me in summer and I'll be a **happy snowman!**

Obviously, the expectation is that the word is "puddle"

It feels like a lyrical version of deceptive cadence, but I cannot find a succinct term for such an effect.

The linked question accepts the answer "Broken Lyric" or "Enjambment", which may still be the answer here, but I am certain that these are two different effects.

Comment: This was asked before but got no answer https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403207/is-there-a-specific-term-for-ending-a-rhyming-line-with-something-unexpected

Comment: There _are_ answers to your question at [Is there a term for this word play where a song intentionally avoids completing a rhyme?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168461/is-there-a-term-for-this-word-play-where-a-song-intentionally-avoids-completing) (eg 'subverted rhyme'. Also at [What are the names/terms for an anticipated but missing rhyme/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346245/what-are-the-names-terms-for-an-anticipated-but-missing-rhyme/346495#346495). One can also find 'mind rhyme' and 'teasing rhyme' in another duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would accept your answer of "Subverted Rhyme" and/or Mind Rhyme.

Comment: The targeted dupe question is not the same.

Comment: 'My' 'answers' are _from_ the duplicates.